# UIPickerView rotation selection problem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

Currently my UIPickerView's wheels DO rotate on the simulator even if it's ios3.2.

Anyway on my iphone->settings->general-> about the ios version is 3.0.1
The thing is, that pickerviews' wheels do not rotate like in simulator 3.2 nor on iphone 4.0.
I'll have to keep on clikcing on the items above in order to scroll down the items above and vice versa. you can't just click on an item and drag in order to scroll like 10 items to the top.

So i just want to make sure if somebody really knows about this issue. Because i couldn't find anything on google/ apple. i've been searching for a long time now.
So if anybody can confirm that on ios 3.0.1 the pickerviews does not function the way they do on new iOSs
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually it is so.
ios 3.0.1 has different uipickerview than in the newer frameworks